# Stored Procedure not returning multiple rows using Cursor in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

Its a sample procedure which I have seen [Blog written by Kevin Bedell](http://www.kbedell.com/2009/03/02/a-simple-example-of-a-mysql-stored-procedure-that-uses-a-cursor/) I am not able to fetch all records from below procedure in mysql. When I call this procedure its returning single row -

Stored Procedure -

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_cursor_example`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_cursor_example`(
   IN name_in VARCHAR(255)
)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE name_val VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE status_update_val VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
  DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE friends_cur CURSOR FOR
     SELECT
        `name`
     , status_update
     FROM test.friend_status
     WHERE `name` = name_in;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET no_more_rows = TRUE;
OPEN friends_cur;
 SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows;
  the_loop: LOOP
  FETCH  friends_cur
 INTO   name_val
,      status_update_val;
IF no_more_rows THEN
    CLOSE friends_cur;
    LEAVE the_loop;
END IF;
SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;
END LOOP the_loop;
SELECT name_val, status_update_val;
-- SELECT num_rows, loop_cntr;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

run using  -

```
call usp_cursor_example('John');
```

It should return 4 rows but it is returning only first row among 4.

Table Structure  -

```
drop table if exists test.friend_status; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`friend_status` (
    `id`            INTEGER(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name`          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `status_update` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

insert into test.friend_status
    (name, status_update)
  values
      ('John',  'Woke up. Guiness for Brkfst.')
    , ('Fred',  'is thinking about joining the circus')
    , ('Erin',  "Getting ready for a job interview")
    , ('Amy',   'at work and dreaming of kittens')
    , ('John',  'Watching Scooby Doo reruns. Guiness for Lunch.')
    , ('Amy',   'dreaming of fuzzy slippers and wedding dresses')
    , ('Julie', 'is hating working two jobs')
    , ('John',  'Out of the shower finally. Guiness for Dinner.')
    , ('Erin',  "if I don't get this job, I'll be asking 'Paper or Plastic?'")
    , ('Amy',   'dreaming of Meeting Mr. Right!')
    , ('Erin',  'Nailed the job interview -- calling John to celebrate!')
    , ('Amy',   'John called -- meeting him at the pub!')
    , ('John',  'Heading out to meet friends for some Guiness!')
;
```

I have seen no of answers in stack overflow but using these answers I am not able to fetch all records. Please suggest me what is the way to fetch these records from stored procedure?

Comment: Your stored procedure appears to be doing the job. `SELECT name_val, status_update_val;` should return a single record and should be with NULLs values. See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dba41/1).

Comment: @wchiquito - Thanks for your suggestion but I want to see four records of 'John' not the no of records. I have removed the another select statement from my question.

Comment: The previous demo shows that the cursor is operating properly, now, the question is: do you need a cursor to see the four records?. With a simple query it gets what it needs. See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7020b/1).

Comment: @wchiquito - I really appreciate your effort but I want to fetch all records using cursor only because I want to do some manipulation in field values using cursor and then show all records. I have shown you the sample of stored procedure but actually is doing more task after fetch from cursor.

Comment: One option is to use a temporary table. See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98940/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name_val, status_update_val;
```

Place the above line inside the Loop for getting all records.